# iOS Bluetooth CBCharacteristic UUID deprecated?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

In the latest Apple docs, the UUID property of a CBCharacteristic has a line drawn through it, and the notation that it is available only in 5.0 through 7.1. But the word "deprecated", which you usually expect to see, is nowhere in sight.

More to the point, there is no suggestion of how else we can identify a characteristic, e.g. when we are passed one in the delegate method peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:. In that method, it is critical to decide *which* characteristic I am dealing with. The descriptors member of the CBCharacteristic instance is nil. What else is there? How does Apple intend for us to distinguish between characteristics? The whole point of UUIDs is identification...

Comment: You can use CBDescriptors and the corresponding delegate methods

Comment: `NSLog(@"descriptors %@", characteristic.descriptors);`

yields

    `descriptors (null)`

It is hard to see how this will help any.

Comment: Actually, after testing, the UUID property is still available on CBCharacteristic in iOS 8.  I am not sure what is up with the documentation

Comment: I should have checked that. Yes, even in a project with Deployment Target set to 8.0, you can (i.e. the compiler does not complain) access the UUID member of a CBCharacteristic. Hmm. The same strikethrough appears in CBService too. Documentation bug? It looks explicit and deliberate, but could be the result of some automated process, and a little Garbage In.

Comment: You should award an answer to one of the ones below - its common courtesy especially since both are correct and just saved me some time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UUID turned into an inherited attribute from iOS8
Here is the evidence from Apple's document
[CoreBluetooth Changes in IOS8 API diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/CoreBluetooth.html)

### CBAttribute.h (Added)

Added CBAttribute
Added CBAttribute.UUID

### CBCharacteristic.h

Removed CBCharacteristic.UUID
Modified CBCharacteristic
Superclasses:
From    NSObject
To  CBAttribute

---

And many other basic CoreBluetooth classes(who contains UUID) adopts this change
However, class reference of CBCharacteristic still says it inherits from NSObject.
So it is misguiding and developers can easily understand UUID as a deprecated attribute in iOS8

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining that! Documentation from Apple is vague or ambiguous in so many cases...

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the header for CBCharacteristic sheds some light on this. There is no more UUID property in the class, but CBCharacteristic is now a subclass of CBAttribute, which *does* have the UUID property. And this (new) parent class is marked as being available starting in iOS 8.

This can explain why the UUID member has a strikethrough, but no "deprecated" warning: you can still get the UUID, but it is inherited rather than belonging to CBAttribute directly.

Comment: I just discovered this as well, because the documentation is seriously misleading... Since iOS 8, CBService, CBCharacteristic, and CBDescriptor all inherit from CBAttribute, which *does* have the UUID property.