# Get uuid in didreceivewriterequests ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I'm making BLE trnasport between tizen and ios using ble.  I can send and receive data but I want to add some logic.
IOS function, didreceivewriterequests() callback is called when ios receive data and I want to store received data to a list with uuid.
Tizen already have this logic.  But I don't know how to get uuid to identify what uuid is including data.  I want to get the data in other funciton with a list by uuid.
How to get uuid in didreceivewriterequests() callback?
Thank you.

- As I see, CBATTRequest.characteristic.UUID is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`characteristic.uuid` is not deprecated. You need to access it from each request in the requests array. From there you can retreive the `UUID` of the characteristic.

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
    for request in requests {
        let id = request.characteristic.uuid
        print("ID is \(id.uuidString)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193041/central-writing-characteristic-to-peripheral-ios-core-bluetooth before I question.  But I see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/CoreBluetooth.html too.  It show 'Removed CBCharacteristic.UUID' and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169472/ios-bluetooth-cbcharacteristic-uuid-deprecated too.

Comment: If you copy and paste my code into your project and run that, what happens?

Comment: `UUID` was removed from `CBCharacteristic` because it was moved to the superclass `CBAttribute`; So it is still available as it is not deprecated on that class - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbattribute

Comment: Than, How can I get uuid?  CBATTRequest* reuqest;  request.characteristic.uuid show 'property 'uuid' not foun on object of type 'CBCharacteristic *'.

Comment: Oh I can get uuid of characteristic but I want to get uuid of service.  When I connect to remote device with CBMutableService alloc...  As I know, there are 2 UUID.  One is service uuid and the other is characteristic uuid.  To connect remote device, scanning service uuid and search characteristic uuid.  Is it possible to find service uuid in the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
  func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {

     for writeRequest in requests {

        print(characteristic.uuid.uuidString)
     }
  }
```